# How to build boost 1.63 for both visual studio 2015 and 2013 (to have vc120 and vc140 libs)?

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I have to use Windows 10 Enterprise and have Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2013 installed, since I'm using both for different projects. I've successfully installed boost 1.63 for VS 2015 from Visual Studio Prompt 2015 following the official guide:

```
bootstraps.bat vc15
.\b2 --prefix=path/to/boost/builds/for2015
```

and found all my vc140 libs. 
Now I'm trying to do the same for VS 2013 from Visual Studio Prompt 2013 by repeating the steps

```
bootstraps.bat vc12
.\b2 --prefix=path/to/boost/builds/for2013
```

but something is going wrong and I find vc140 libs in my path/to/boost/builds/for2013 folder instead of vc120 ones. I've simply tried to rename them, but it seems they are really vc140 and not vc120.

Any ideas about what to change to get vc120? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Life is too short to troubleshoot bjam, just [download the prebuilt binaries](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.63.0/).

Comment: Build a version for each. They don't have to be in the same directory. And get used to it! I even build separate version for 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: thanks, @HansPassant! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing worked with [prebuilt binaries](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.63.0/)

Thank you, @Hans!